# How to use nested loops in joblib library in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

Actual code looks like:

```
def compute_score(row_list,column_list): 

    for i in range(len(row_list)):
            for j in range(len(column_list)):
                tf_score = self.compute_tf(column_list[j],row_list[i])
```

I am tying to achieve multi-processing i.e. at every iteration of `j` I want to pool `column_list`. Since `compute_tf` function is slow I want to multi-process it.

I've found have to do it using `joblib` in Python, But I am unable to workaround with nested loops.

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(self.compute_tf)<some_way_to_use_nested_loops>)
```

This is what is to be achieved.
It would be a great help if any solution on this is provided or any-other solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another solution without having to implement a generator function, is to use the nested list comprehension for the generator:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(self.compute_tf)(i, j) for j in column_list for i in row_list)
```

The order will be given as:

```
[(i, j) for j in range(10) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not understanding your part about Parallel.  However, your code can be simplified to this:

```
def compute_score(row_list,column_list): 

    for i in row_list:
            for j in column_list:
                tf_score = self.compute_tf(j,i)
```

It may be useful to create a generator that yields each j,i so that you can process them outside of the generator

```
def compute_pairs(row_list,column_list): 

    for i in row_list:
            for j in column_list:
                yield j, i
```

then use:

```
 scored = [compute_tf(j,i) for j, i in compute_pairs(row_list, column_list)]
```

Comment: `compute_pairs` doesn't even need to be spelled out - `itertools.product` does the exact same thing.