# Parallelizing four nested loops in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, joblib

I have a fairly straightforward nested for loop that iterates over four arrays:

```
for a in a_grid:
    for b in b_grid:
        for c in c_grid:
            for d in d_grid:
                do_some_stuff(a,b,c,d)  # perform calculations and write to file
```

Maybe this isn't the most efficient way to perform calculations over a 4D grid to begin with. I know `joblib` is capable of parallelizing two nested for loops like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423975/how-to-use-nested-loops-in-joblib-library-in-python?rq=1), but I'm having trouble generalizing it to four nested loops. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried the obvious? `Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(do_some_stuff)(a, b, c, d) for a in a_grid for b in b_grid for c in c_grid for d in d_grid)`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I usually use code of this form:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import itertools
import multiprocessing

#Generate values for each parameter
a = range(10)
b = range(10)
c = range(10)
d = range(10)

#Generate a list of tuples where each tuple is a combination of parameters.
#The list will contain all possible combinations of parameters.
paramlist = list(itertools.product(a,b,c,d))

#A function which will process a tuple of parameters
def func(params):
  a = params[0]
  b = params[1]
  c = params[2]
  d = params[3]
  return a*b*c*d

#Generate processes equal to the number of cores
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

#Distribute the parameter sets evenly across the cores
res  = pool.map(func,paramlist)
```

Comment: Is `paramlist =  [a,b,c,d]` ?

Comment: I ran this script, and ```paramlist``` looks like

[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 0, 3),
 (0, 0, 0, 4),
 (0, 0, 0, 5),
 (0, 0, 0, 6),
 (0, 0, 0, 7),
 (0, 0, 0, 8),
 (0, 0, 0, 9),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 2),
 (0, 0, 1, 3),
 (0, 0, 1, 4),
 (0, 0, 1, 5),
 (0, 0, 1, 6),
 (0, 0, 1, 7),
 (0, 0, 1, 8),
 (0, 0, 1, 9),
 (0, 0, 2, 0),
 (0, 0, 2, 1),
 (0, 0, 2, 2),
 (0, 0, 2, 3),
 (0, 0, 2, 4),
...
 (0, 9, 9, 6),
 (0, 9, 9, 7),
 (0, 9, 9, 8),
 (0, 9, 9, 9),
 ...]

Answer (score 3):

If you use a tool that makes it easy to parallelize two nested loops, but not four, you can use `itertools.product` to reduce four nested `for` loops into two:

```
from itertools import product

for a, b in product(a_grid, b_grid):
    for c, d in product(c_grid, d_grid):
        do_some_stuff(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: Significant acceleration, that's true. However, it is not parallelization but optimization. Still consuming one core.

Comment: @TedoVrbanec By parallelization I referred to iteration over both sequences at once, not in the sense of using two CPUs. Also note that using `itertools.product` is no optimization either, it's just a different way of expressing the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The number of jobs is not related to the number of nested loops.
In that other answer, it happened to be `n_jobs=2` and 2 loops, but the two are completely unrelated.

Think of it this way:
You have a bunch of function calls to make; in your case (unrolling the loops):

```
do_some_stuff(0,0,0,0)
do_some_stuff(0,0,0,1)
do_some_stuff(0,0,0,2)
do_some_stuff(0,0,1,0)
do_some_stuff(0,0,1,1)
do_some_stuff(0,0,1,2)
...
```

and you want to distribute those function calls across some number of jobs.
You could use 2 jobs, or 10, or 100, it doesn't matter. `Parallel` takes care of distributing the work for you.

Comment: Right. I was mostly having trouble with structuring the code. I'm new to multiprocessing/joblib, so @Hamms's obvious solution somehow didn't come to mind. It does work though.