# How to paralllelize this nested loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, joblib

I'm using joblib with Dask to parallellize my code that has the following loop structure:

```
def main():
    for semtype in semtypes:
        test = get_valid_systems(systems, semtype)
        expressions = get_ensemble_pairs(test)
    
        for c in expressions:

            <do stuff>
```

The first attempt was to rewrite it with the inner loop as:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for semtype in semtypes:
        test = get_valid_systems(systems, semtype)
        expressions = get_ensemble_pairs(test)

        print('SYSTEMS FOR SEMTYPE', semtype, 'ARE', test)
    
        with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
            joblib.Parallel(verbose=10)(joblib.delayed(main)(c) for c in expressions)
```

which work fine.

Now, I'd like to add both loops, as in:

```
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):

    joblib.Parallel(verbose=100)(joblib.delayed(main)(semtype, c) for c in get_ensemble_pairs(get_valid_systems(systems, semtype)) for semtype in semtypes)
```

However, I'm getting an error that `name 'semtype' is not defined`. I'm assuming this is a scoping issue wrt the function calls in my `Paraallel` statement. I'm not quite sure how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer most loop should come first.

```
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):

    joblib.Parallel(verbose=100)(joblib.delayed(main)(semtype, c) for semtype in semtypes for c in get_ensemble_pairs(get_valid_systems(systems, semtype)))
```

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing! I was going by this: [how-to-use-nested-loops-in-joblib-library-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423975/how-to-use-nested-loops-in-joblib-library-in-python?rq=1)